# Jmeter - how to pass a csrfmiddlewaretoken to a http request without getting 403 or Forbidden issues?

Tags: jmeter, csrf

Can you explain how to construct a relevant HTTP Header or HTTP Request parameter holding CSRF value when an HTTP request has to be passed with a csrfmiddlewaretoken in Jmeter ?

Answer (score 1):

CSRF protection can be handled just like any other dynamic mandatory request parameter or field, the right term to perform search on in performance testing world is [Correlation](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html)

Check out [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) guide, it looks like to be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement correlation, after you have recorded the script. This is useful to pass dynamic values between different requests.

- http://apache-jmeter.blogspot.com/2011/12/correlation-regular-expression.html
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8bBiCeQ88w

If you have already implemented correlation and you are still getting errors, then you should bypass the token generation by writing code in Beanshell sampler to generate csrfmiddlewaretoken and then pass it to the next HTTP request (as per requirement).

hope this will help.